# Posting SVG string to Controller works locally but not on server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fabricjs

I have a form that I'm posting that contains 2 numeric values and a long string containing an SVG (generated using Fabricjs). The controller uploads the SVG and outputs a PDF containing it. The reason I'm using a standard form post instead of Ajax POST is because I understand that ajax cannot return a file download.

I have maxJsonLength, aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers, and maxRequestLength all set to values much higher than what's involved here (10k of text), and I don't think the json-related ones come into play here anyway since it's a standard form post.

This works perfectly when I run it locally in Visual Studio. Once it's published to the server, it fails. I attached to the process with remote debug, and it's not even hitting the controller. I have a similar controller action that also accepts the same SVG string, and that's not working either.

In the network console, the action returns a 200. When I look at the headers, I can't see any difference between what's posting to the server vs. what I see locally. Elmah is not capturing any error, so I can't even figure out where to go at this point to find out what's wrong.

Here's the form. I added the enctype at the suggestion of another SO post, but that doesn't make a difference.

```
<form action="/Product/ExportSVG" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8" id="svgForm" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" id="svgProjNo" name="svgProjNo" value="1111">
    <input type="hidden" id="svgLineID" name="svgLineID" value="">
    <input type="hidden" id="svgData" name="svgData" value="">
</form>
```

The script that posts the form:

```
var svgtext = canvas.toSVG(null, reviver);
$("#svgLineID").val($("#LineItem_ParentID").val());
$("#svgData").val(svgtext);
$('#svgForm').trigger('submit');
```

The controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ExportSVG(decimal svgProjNo, decimal svgLineID, string svgData)
{ 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Try to narrow the issue by making request with very little data in svgData parameter just to ensure controller is working. Once confirmed controller is working then it would be SVG data in post making difference.

Comment: are you using fabricjs to generate the svgs? maybe that tabs and newlines are bothering you? did you try to remove them with some regexp in js and send svg data without them? i do not really know asp.net

Comment: @Leadfoot: I tried it with an empty string instead of the SVG string and that hit my breakpoint inside the controller, so it has to be that string. It's coming through URL encoded, which I thought would work fine. I can't figure out why it would work locally and not on the server.

Comment: @AndreaBogazzi It looks like it's escaping everything correctly - it posts as one long string with the brackets, quotes, etc. all replaced as I'd expect.

Comment: An example:

    svgData=%3C%3Fxml+version%3D%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22+standalone%3D%22no%22+%3F%3E%3C%21DOCTYPE+svg+PUBLIC+%22-%2F%2FW3C%2F%2FDTD+SVG+1.1%2F%2FEN%22+%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2FGraphics%2FSVG%2F1.1%2FDTD%2Fsvg11.dtd%22%3E%0D%0A%3Csvg+xmlns%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2000%2Fsvg%22+xmlns%3Axlink%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2Fxlink%22+version%3D%221.1%22+width%3D%22663%22+height%3D%22556%22+xml%3Aspace%3D%22preserve%22%3E%3Cdesc%3ECreated+with+Fabric.js+1.5.0%3C%2Fdesc%3E%3Cdefs%3E%3C%2Fdefs%3E%3Cg+transform%3D%22translate%

Comment: locally and remote can be everything, different version of iis, different security setting, not a microsoft expert thought. isn't there some log to check? like access_log in apache to see who is posting and where.

Comment: I've checked the IIS logs and it shows a 200 as if everything went right. Our exception logger shows nothing. At least I know it's something with the SVG now, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: try to upload the svg string without the "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no" ?><!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">"   would be first thing i remove to do a test.

Comment: @jlkmpls Try encoding the SVG data in base 64 format. See if it makes any difference. It could be some MVC/IIS rule putting some constraints on data.

Comment: @Leadfoot: That was it!! Thanks so much. If you leave that as an answer on this post I can mark it as the solution.

Comment: @jlkmpls glad that I was able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to encode SVG data in base 64 format.